# How to get streaming url from online streaming radio station

Tags: javascript, android, html, stream

I've been asked to make unofficial online streaming android application for a certain radio station.
I've experience with streaming in android for certain mp3 or whatever stream.
But I don't know the `stream url` to provide in `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url)`.

Is there any way to get the stream url from the ofiicial streaming page for ex. [this radio stream](http://tunein.com/radio/HD-fm-1042-s93614/)?

Comment: I don't ask here unless I can't find it on internet, I've googled and searched stakoverflow

Answer (score 20, accepted):

not that hard,

if you take a look at the page source, you'll see that it uses to stream the audio via shoutcast.

this is the stream url

"StreamUrl": "http://stream.radiotime.com/listen.stream?streamIds=3244651&rti=c051HQVbfRc4FEMbKg5RRVMzRU9KUBw%2fVBZHS0dPF1VIExNzJz0CGQtRcX8OS0o0CUkYRFJDDW8LEVRxGAEOEAcQXko%2bGgwSBBZrV1pQZgQZZxkWCA4L%7e%7e%7e",

which returns a JSON like that:

```
{
    "Streams": [
        {
            "StreamId": 3244651,
            "Reliability": 92,
            "Bandwidth": 64,
            "HasPlaylist": false,
            "MediaType": "MP3",
            "Url": "http://mp3hdfm32.hala.jo:8132",
            "Type": "Live"
        }
    ]
}
```

i believe that's the url you need:
http://mp3hdfm32.hala.jo:8132

[this is the station WebSite](http://www.bliss1042.com/)

Comment: That's it! before posting I tried inspect element and find something like that but I couldn't, thank you

Comment: I'm currently having the same problem
I need to play audio at [this website](http://tunein.com/radio/local/)
help me out

Comment: This can hardly qualify as an answer. It applies **only to the station of the example** given in the description! It doesn't apply to the question "How to get streaming url from online streaming radio station", which is for **any radio station**!!

Answer (score 5):

Edited ZygD's answer for python 3.x.:

```
import re
import urllib.request
import string
url1 = input("Please enter a URL from Tunein Radio: ");
request = urllib.request.Request(url1);
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request);
raw_file = response.read().decode('utf-8');
API_key = re.findall(r"StreamUrl\":\"(.*?),\"",raw_file);
#print API_key;
#print "The API key is: " + API_key[0];
request2 = urllib.request.Request(str(API_key[0]));
response2 = urllib.request.urlopen(request2);
key_content = response2.read().decode('utf-8');
raw_stream_url = re.findall(r"Url\": \"(.*?)\"",key_content);
bandwidth = re.findall(r"Bandwidth\":(.*?),", key_content);
reliability = re.findall(r"lity\":(.*?),", key_content);
isPlaylist = re.findall(r"HasPlaylist\":(.*?),",key_content);
codec = re.findall(r"MediaType\": \"(.*?)\",", key_content);
tipe = re.findall(r"Type\": \"(.*?)\"", key_content);
total = 0
for element in raw_stream_url:
    total = total + 1
i = 0
print ("I found " + str(total) + " streams.");
for element in raw_stream_url:
    print ("Stream #" + str(i + 1));
    print ("Stream stats:");
    print ("Bandwidth: " + str(bandwidth[i]) + " kilobytes per second.");
    print ("Reliability: " + str(reliability[i]) + "%");
    print ("HasPlaylist: " + str(isPlaylist[i]));
    print ("Stream codec: " + str(codec[i]));
    print ("This audio stream is " + tipe[i].lower());
    print ("Pure streaming URL: " + str(raw_stream_url[i]));
i = i + 1
input("Press enter to close")
```

Comment: I had to append `http:` to the API Key: `request2 = urllib.request.Request("http:%s" % API_key[0]);`

Answer (score 5):

The provided answers didn't work for me. I'm adding another answer because this is where I ended up when searching for radio stream urls.

Radio Browser is a searchable site with streaming urls for radio stations around the world:

http://www.radio-browser.info/

Search for a station like [FIP](http://www.radio-browser.info/gui/#!/byname/fip), [Pinguin Radio](http://www.radio-browser.info/gui/#!/byname/pinguin%20radio) or [Radio Paradise](http://www.radio-browser.info/gui/#!/byname/radio%20paradise), then click the save button, which downloads a PLS file that you can open in your radioplayer (Rhythmbox), or you open the file in a text editor and copy the URL to add in Goodvibes.

Answer (score 4):

Shahar's answer was really helpful, but I found it quite tedious to do this all myself, so I made a nifty little Python program:

```
import re
import urllib2
import string
url1 = raw_input("Please enter a URL from Tunein Radio: ");
open_file = urllib2.urlopen(url1);
raw_file = open_file.read();
API_key = re.findall(r"StreamUrl\":\"(.*?),",raw_file);
#print API_key;
#print "The API key is: " + API_key[0];
use_key = urllib2.urlopen(str(API_key[0]));
key_content = use_key.read();
raw_stream_url = re.findall(r"Url\": \"(.*?)\"",key_content);
bandwidth = re.findall(r"Bandwidth\":(.*?),", key_content);
reliability = re.findall(r"lity\":(.*?),", key_content);
isPlaylist = re.findall(r"HasPlaylist\":(.*?),",key_content);
codec = re.findall(r"MediaType\": \"(.*?)\",", key_content);
tipe = re.findall(r"Type\": \"(.*?)\"", key_content);
total = 0
for element in raw_stream_url:
    total = total + 1
i = 0
print "I found " + str(total) + " streams.";
for element in raw_stream_url:
    print "Stream #" + str(i + 1);
    print "Stream stats:";
    print "Bandwidth: " + str(bandwidth[i]) + " kilobytes per second."
    print "Reliability: " + str(reliability[i]) + "%"
    print "HasPlaylist: " + str(isPlaylist[i]) + "."
    print "Stream codec: " + str(codec[i]) + "."
    print "This audio stream is " + tipe[i].lower() + "."
    print "Pure streaming URL: " + str(raw_stream_url[i]) + ".";
    i = i + 1
raw_input("Press enter to close TMUS.")
```

It's basically Shahar's solution automated.

Comment: To get the whole list replace with this **`API_key = re.findall(r"StreamUrl\":\"(.*?),\"",raw_file)`**  I just added `\"` on the regex

Answer (score 1):

When you go to a stream url, you get offered a file. feed this file to a parser to extract the contents out of it. the file is (usually) plain text and contains the url to play.